# Why is it preferably to use Awake and OnDestroy instead of constructor and destructor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity and there is my flow - I have an object and I need to initialize my `.dll`, then I also need somewhere to realize my `.dll`, so there are 2 options (as for me) to do it

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player()
    {
        //1 option for call some INIT methods from .dll
    }

    ~Player()
    {
        //1 option for call some RELEASE methods from .dll
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        //2 option for call some INIT methods from .dll
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        //2 option for call some RELEASE methods from .dll
    }
}
```

Actually I use for this purpose `constructor` + `destructor`, but according to the examples I faced I understand that it is not a best practice in Unity, so question is - why? What is the problem here?

Comment: Unity is all about **game objects** - it has nothing to do with conventional OO.  Naturally you of course have to use the game object calls, when dealing with game objects.  It's that simpole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity provides a [lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) for handling game related events (loading, update, physics collision...) rather than memory related events (construction, destruction).

CREATION:

You cannot make calls into the unity api (e.g. `GetComponent<T>(...)`) inside your constructor, since the `MonoBehaviours` are simply decorators of a certain `GameObject` and it is not verified that the `GameObject` creation is finished when your constructor runs!

Unity's `Awake` runs exactly once for every object, when the object creation is finished and all `MonoBehaviour` got added.

DESTRUCTION:

Also as c# provides out of the box memory management an objects destructor is called at an uncertain point in time, once there are no more references to an object (not as soon as the last reference is removed, not even when calling `IDisposable.Dispose()`).

Unity's `OnDestroy` is called exactly when the object gets "destroyed" thus becoming unusable in Unity's lifecycle. This is the point in time you need to know, when your game is running. c#'s destructor is completely useless here.